# Nagios: check host service even if host is down

Tags: nagios

Is there a way to force nagios 3 to check a particular host's service (and notify such events) even if the host is down?

The reason I ask so is that I have a service that checks if a host's IP matches its DNS entry, and this can (and needs) be checked even if the host is down.

Also, would it be possible to still have notifications of the particular service, even if the host has `notifications_enabled 0`? Or is there any other way of disabling the host's notifications, while keeping the service's?

Answer (score 1):

The IP matching DNS service should be connected to a fake host called "DNS" or something; and use a dummy check for the fake "DNS" host that just does an "exit 0".

You could also connect it to your real DNS server: if that server is down then there's not much point in trying to check the DNS.

Comment: Doing this in a fake host means you can't use the information already available on each host's `host_name` and `address`, though, so you end up having to duplicate all the information

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have a service be checked even if the host is down. There's an implied dependency for all services on a given host.

To answer your second question: Services have their own `notifications_enabled` setting, so you can have services notify even if their parent host doesn't. However, if it's not defined, it will inherit from the host. (There are only a few settings that inherit from the host. See [Implied Inheritance on this page](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectinheritance.html)).